# SSRS Report Manager

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, reportmanager

I am implementing an SSRS project but I have issues with the deployment phase.

**My requirements**

1. Deploy the report to the reporting server
2. Allow Users to access the reports from a custom web application.
3. Users should access the reports with any browser
4. I don't have a sharepoint/Domain authentication so I am using a custom web app

**My Challenges**

After deploying the reports to the report server, If I try to access the Report Manager Url from my client system I receive an prompt requesting for the Windows Login Credentials of my Reporting Server.
I want disable this prompt.

Please I need your help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the data source of that report (or of the shared data source if it uses one) and choose the option "Credentials stored securely in the report server", adding the credentials appropriate to the data source there.

The problem you're having is that the default data source authentication (as with SQL Server itself) is Windows integrated authentication, and that's why you're getting prompted for credentials from a browser connection.

See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159736.aspx) for an overview on how to store credentials with the data source.

Comment: I have changed the data source to properties to Credentials Stored securely on the datasource, I also check the Impersonate the authenticated user after the connection. But still the problem persist. Anytime I try to open the report manager url from another computer on my network, I am prompted with a windows login screen.

Comment: Is the Report Manager web application configured to use Windows authentication in IIS? Have a look in the IIS Manager (2012) or Internet Services Manager (2008). Check the Reports webapp while you're in there.

Answer (score 0):

In your web application's web.config add identity impersonate="true" and SSRS 2012 does not use IIS.